# Groovy/Java: match command option with quoted value

Tags: java, regex, groovy

I try to match if a command string contains a quoted value as one of its option. Below is what I have gotten so far:

```
def pattern = ~/\s+[-]{1,2}\w\s+'.*'/

assert "cmd -o '{}'" =~ pattern
assert 'cmd -o \'{"a": "b"}\'' =~ pattern
assert 'cmd --option \'{"a": "b"}\'' =~ pattern // failed
assert 'cmd --long-option \'{"a": "b"}\'' =~ pattern // failed
```

Any suggestion how to make long option works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex to match all the cases provided in your question:

```bash
\s+-{1,2}\w[\w-]*\s+'[^']*'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DYtLqN/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespace
- `-{1,2}`: Match 1 or 2 hyphens
- `\w[\w-]*`: Match 1+ of word or hyphen characters starting with a word character
- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespace
- `'[^']*'`: Match a string wrapped in single quotes

Answer (score 3):

Just an addendum to @anubhava's answer. Feel free to comment your regex using the `(?x)` whitespace/comment flag:

```
def pattern = ~/(?x)
    \s+      # 1+ whitespace
    -{1,2}   # 1 or 2 hyphens
    \w[\w-]* # 1+ of word or hyphen characters starting with a word character
    \s+      # 1+ whitespace
    '[^']*'  # a string wrapped in single quotes
    /
```